# Craft CMS 3 - Manual database backup

Tags: craft3, database, back-up

Since my hosting provider is blocking `mysqldump` on its server, I'm trying to do a manual backup of my database in order to import the DB into my test environment.

I'm stuck on the elements to ignore since a manual export on PHPMyAdmin (prod env) and then import to PHPMyAdmin (dev env) environment triggers errors.

Do you guys have any experience in manual backups?

Thanks! :)

Comment: "triggers errors" - what errors are you getting?

Comment: I tried different setups, ignoring the tables but I still get stuck with new elements, for instance: 
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'crft_categorygroups'

#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Is there a list of table that  I should ignore?

Comment: Did you already tried to export the DB using SSH `./craft backup/db` command? Perhaps there's wrong settings used with your manual export.

Answer (score 1):

When you do your export in phpmyadmin, make sure you check the 'disable foreign key checks' box in the custom options:

[image]